# TFS error: when I'm giving checkin in my project one Rotativa.dll bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs, rotativa

I am using ASP .NET MVC 4 with Entity Framework 4.5

I downloaded the nuget something to be able to export my data pro PDF and found one called RotativaW7. The project is working normal but I try to check in the project to publish to TFS and is giving the following error message:

*ERROR: Multiple errors occurred during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window.*

..\packages\RotativaW7.1.5.4\RotativaW7.1.5.4.nupkg: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The cancellation of an existing connection was forced by the remote host.

nuget:
Install-Package RotativaW7 -Version 1.5.4

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package contains an .exe, are you sure TFS allows you to check in executable files?